# Checking Range of Values to Given Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have scoured the web for an answer for this, but I've yet to find anything and it's driving me out of my mind because I know the solution must be simple.

Similar to `VLOOKUP`, I'm trying to check a range of values against a single cell and return literally anything if any of the cells in the range match. I can't do the reverse, as the range contains many wildcard strings, whereas the single cells are complete strings. Or maybe I could do that, but I don't know how to approach it.

Literally any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated. I've tried many iterations of `MATCH`, `VLOOKUP`, and `IF` statements to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are getting at.  But if you are trying to see if the value of one cell matches any values in a range you could use the `COUNTIF` function.

Comment: so, you have a list of words, and you want to know if any of them are in a particular cell?

Comment: @SeanC correct, though they have wildcards as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example grid:

[image: Text grid]

This formula will tell you how many words/patterns that your sentence contains:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1:A5,C1)))))
```

this means that if your list matches multiple words, you will get a count of how many it matches, so if you change **C1** to `test words watt` you will get `3` as the result of the formula

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any value in column E against the list on A1:A5, if you find that value it will prompt you.

```
Sub ok()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("E1:E5")
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    For i = 1 To 5
        If cel.Value Like Range("A" & i).Value Then
            MsgBox "Found " & cel.Value
        End If
    Next
Next cel
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do unfortunately. I'm trying to flip it and compare the range to a given cell. Similar logic may work, but I've yet to find a way to apply it.

Comment: I didn't really want a prompt, but this works just as well. I've marked the above answer as the best answer due to its simplicity, but this one also works.

Comment: you can set the prompt to be a count or variable or whatever your hearts wants to do.